# Call external programs with CMake

Tags: cmake, thrift

I tried to search the CMake documentation, but I couldn't figure out how to call external programs from CMake.

There are few things I want to do.

1. Compile other third-party dependencies that uses a makefile
2. Compile [Thrift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Thrift) definition files to C++ / Python stubs.
3. Compile [Cython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cython) definition files.

Another question is, what is a good way to handle those cases anyway? It feels like calling a shell script directly from CMake doesn't feel so clean, when "C" in CMake stands for Cross Platform.

EDIT: I have few extra questions. Before, in my build, I prebuilt my dependencies, and the project itself used FIND_PACKAGE(...) to find the header / libraries for the dependencies.

Now, I'm ExternalProject_Add() to compile the dependencies, but the problem is, all my FindXYZ() functions fails when I run `cmake .`, because the dependencies aren't present when CMake gets executed.

How should I include the third-party libraries in my project in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html

2+3. can be hacked with CONFIGURE_COMMAND/BUILD_COMMAND/INSTALL_COMMAND

Comment: Wow, my respect towards CMake has gone up considerably after discovering ExternProject_Add(). I'll try out other stuff soon.

Comment: Thanks Anycorn. However, I have bit more questions regarding my build. Would you be kind enough to answer, if you can? Thanks!

Comment: @not sure if I understand question, can you elaborate?

Comment: I ended up changing my makefiles. basically, FIND_PACKAGE() commands are executed while makefiles are generated by cmake. I used to use FIND_PACKAGE() to find third party libraries for my project. However, if I start using ExternalPackage_Add(), building of the third party library occurs after the makefile has been generated. thus, cmake couldn't proceed to generating makefiles, because it couldn't find dependencies referenced by FIND_PACKAGE().

Comment: I just removed find_packages(), because since i control how the external packages are being compiled, I know exactly where the compiled headers / libraries are located. So i just referred to those locations in include_directories(), and target_link_libraries().